# the message in the message box is not printing the addition of the two numbers

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *

root=Tk()
Label(root,text="first").grid(row=0)
Label(root,text="second").grid(row=2)
e1=Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0,column=2)
e2=Entry(root)
e2.grid(row=2,column=2)
a=e1.get()
b=e2.get()
def add():
    c=a+b
    s=showinfo(title="answers",message='addition='+c)
```

Comment: Then what it is printing?  Also, please format your code.

Comment: it should print the calculated value of c,but it is not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be getting the value from the entry widget immediately after creating the widget. You need to wait until the user types something in.

You also seem to have the problem that nothing is calling `add`, so it seems to be impossible for the message to even show up at all.